# Git Head Points at Two Local Branches Roll One Back by a Commit

Tags: git

I have a situation where HEAD points to two branches and branch configuration is as follows:

```
* 76ee9315 - (HEAD -> branch_A, branch_B) 
*   242bf88d - (origin/branch_A) Merge branch 'branch_A' into branch_B 
|\
| * c5e6b6b9 - (origin/branch_B)
```

How can make it so the latest commit only belongs to branch_A, whereas branch_B is rolled back by one commit? I tried checking out branch_B and doing a hard reset by one commit. However, that wiped the commit from both branches, and I had to get if back via reflog.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple

```
git branch -f branch_B 242bf88d
```

The trick is to understand that branches are just pointers to commits. This command is telling git *hey, set `branch_B` pointer on commit `242bf88d`*.

As a side note, `HEAD` is not pointing to 2 branches. It's rather that you have `branch_A` and `branch_B` pointing to the same commit and `HEAD` is pointing to `branch_A` (as in, that is the branch that is checked out).

Comment: Beautiful and instructive, thanks! That did it!

Comment: But how do you explain "I tried checking out branch_B and doing a hard reset by one commit. However, that wiped the commit from both branches"? That should have worked just fine.

Comment: Well.... then we go into the _need to see commands and output_ terrain. If the hard --reset on `branch_B`took place and then `git log` is called..... you know what happens, right? That _might_ explain why the OP saw it as `branch_A` being wiped out..... but would need to see the exact commands and outputs to be sure.

Comment: I'm always in that terrain. :)